# Cucumber to handle two users in two browsers in one scenario

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am trying to automate one scenario where I need to confirm that two users cannot simultaneously edit one table in an application. My framework is Java cucumber selenium based and using PicoContainer for dependency injection.

My problem is the framework is written in such a way that that it can handle only one user and one browser in a single scenario.

Scenario:
Step 1: User1 logs in with id Access1 in one chrome browser
Step 2: User1 opens a table
Step 3: User2 logs in with id Access2 in another chrome browser
Step 4: User 2 opens the same table and sees error message ' the table is locked by user 1'
Step 5: User 1 logs off
Step 6: User2 tried to open the same table and this time its editable.
Step 7.User 2 logs off

I tried declaring a 2nd driver, it works fine if I close the previously open bbrowser but not simultaneously in the same scenario.

Comment: Did you try executing the scenarios in parallel mode? You can find more information from https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java#junit-5

Comment: This sounds like a scenario that a manual tester should do. I don't know how you are going to sync the two browsers since each will have to be driven by its own script.

Comment: @SrinivasuKaki Parallel run is for two differ scenarios or same scenario in outline. What I am searching is one scenario with two users in parallel.